# Como ler e escrever JSON localmente no Cordova?

Tags: json, apache-cordova, app, localstorage

Preciso de uma solução simples para carregar e atualizar dados de maneira persistente em um APP móvel usando Cordova.

Pensei em fazer criar um `JSON` na pasta raiz da aplicação para carregar os dados na inicialização do APP.

Até da certo, mas, como fazer o inverso?

Por exemplo: o script carrega o JSON e joga na View > o user modifica esses dados de alguma forma > o script da `stringify()` e armazena de volta o JSON atualizado na pasta raiz. Acho que não da pra fazer isso com `POST`.

Vi que da pra fazer usando `localStorage`, mas dessa forma os dados se perdem ao fechar a aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consultando o link de [Storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) da documentação podemos ver que existe diversos métodos, como:

- localStorage
- WebSQL
- IndexedDB
- Ou utilizar algum plugin para fazer armazenamento de forma especifica como a API de arquivos.

No seu caso como você pretende utilizar `JSON` recomendo o uso de um plugin para manipulamento de arquivos. Neste caso você abre o arquivo `JSON` da memória, trabalha com ele e em algum momento grava ele novamente para memória.

Eu mesmo trabalhei em um projeto com armazenamento de arquivo em memória, para isso utilizei um plugin chamado [Cordova Simple File Management](https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement), com ele o processo de gerenciamento de arquivos fica muito mais fácil do que ter que criar funções para acessar a API de arquivos.