# Banco de dados em app híbrido utilizando Cordova

Tags: android, html5, ios, sqlite, apache-cordova

Quais as possíveis e mais viaveis soluções para se usar um banco de dados em um APP hibrido (Android/iOS) feito no Intel XDK (Cordova)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se fala de **Cordova** (Android **e** iOS) as opções são as seguintes:

- LocalStorage
- WebSQL
- Ou plugins para fazer o armazenamento em arquivos em memória.

Existe outras formas de armazenamento também possíveis, se seu aplicativo utilizar uma conexão com a Internet você pode armazenar todos os dados em um servidor e receber/enviar as informações por meio de um WebService.

Se você utilizar um plugin externo para fazer este gerenciamento recomendo a verificação deste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50267/como-ler-e-escrever-json-localmente-no-cordova/50277#50277)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

A tecnologia mais atual e o padrão a ser adotado para desenvolvimento HTML5 é o IndexedDB, apesar de não estar listado no site do cordova os webviews do Android e do IOS suportam IndexedDB e o suporte só tende a melhorar. http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

Aconselho criar um aplicativo de teste e verificar se as implementações nos dispositivos que precisa atendem as suas necessidades.

Existem bibliotecas que permitem acesso via API do IndexedDB mas que nos browsers não suportados usam WebSQL para gravar os dados, pode ser uma solução caso o dispositivo que esteja desenvolvendo não suporte IndexedDB. Um Exemplo é o [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/learn.html).

Comment: O Cordova não oferece ainda suporte a IndexedDB em Android E iOS. É sim possível implementar, porém causa mais problemas e é necessário adaptar o código para cada plataforma. Acho que ele não pode ser considerado uma solução hibrida =/.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Você não precisa utilizar a API do Cordova para acessar recursos HTML5 nativos da WebView onde o aplicativo está sendo executado. Nesse caso pode sim utilizar uma biblioteca JavaScript para resolver o acesso a dados de forma uniforme, que é sim uma solução multiplataforma viável. Não confunda utilizar o Cordova como empacotador, e utilizar a API do Cordova no aplicativo.

Comment: Não confundo isso :), fiz testes em alguns aplicativos com IndexedDB e até hoje só encontrei mais problemas do que vantagens, eu pessoalmente fico longe de utilizar implementações dependente do WebKit porque sei que um dos meus usuários irá utilizar uma versão do Android antiga sem suporte e também não sou muito a favor de sair utilizando polyfill's pela velocidade do Cordova, querendo ou não ele é lento.

Comment: Beleza, performance de fato sofre ao usar qualquer tipo de polyfill, mas ainda assim dependendo da aplicação acho que pode ser uma boa solução. Concordo com você em não depende de webkit, mas acredito fielmente que o IndexedDB vai avançar como padrão. Então preferiria utilizar um polyfill e não ter que mudar os fontes do sistema no futuro. Nesse caso vai depender do uso e do desenvolvedor.