# Rodar Aplicação em 2º Plano Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Cordova que envia os dados (cadastro e imagem) para servidor externo, já está funcionando porém, gostaria de fazer com que caso o usuário não tenha internet no momento do cadastro, a aplicação fica rodando em 2º plano esperando conexão com internet para enviar os dados, como faço isto?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso é relativamente simples já que sua aplicação funciona da forma esperada e você quer apenas adicionar uma novidade/função.

A primeira coisa a ser considerada é criar um serviço para ser executado em segundo plano, existe diversos plugins para facilitar este processo. Você pode verificar os seguintes:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService

Com um serviço em segundo plano você deve esperar (ou escutar)  o evento `online` do Cordova. Ele será emitido assim que o disposítivo se conectar com a Internet. Mais informações sobre como fazer isso neste link [Cordova Online Event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online).

Quando o usuário fizer o cadastro e não possuir nenhuma conexão de internet você deve armazenar as infomações ou mesmo a própria solicitação no disposítivo. Assim que o evento `online` for disparado tu verifica quais informações estão salvas para serem cadastradas e tenta efetuar o cadastro. Porém é valido informar que caso algun dado não esteja correto você terá que trata-los de forma diferente, talvez com alguma notificação.

Para salvar os dados no dispositivo você pode utilizar diversas tecnologias, consulte [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/banco-de-dados-em-app-h%C3%ADbrido-utilizando-cordova/54220#54220) resposta para ter uma visão melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o plugin para checar o status da conexão e coloque a execução em uma lista de tarefas a serem feitas. Quando a conexão voltar, um evento será disparado aí você executa aquela lista de tarefas pendentes de conexão.

Você pode configurar um [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) para de tempos em tempos checar a conexão. Quando ela voltar, você executa a tarefa e cancela o timer.

Verifique um exemplo de utilização do plugin [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: Ok, entendi mas eu preciso que funcione no estilo do "DropBox", mesmo que você feche ou minimize a aplicação no celular ele ainda envia os dados, tem como fazer isto?